# How to remove only text from link wrapping both text and image, with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that contains a list. In each `li` there is an a tag. the a tag contains both text and image. Here is the html:

```
<li class="li-one" style="">    
<a href="#" onclick="return false"><img class="theimg" src="...." width="18" height="12" alt="" title="">myText</a>
</li>
```

I tried using this jQuery but the image is removed too:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){jQuery(".li-one").text("");});
```

How can I remove the text (`myText`) with jQuery?

Comment: You could grab the image, remove everything, and then re-insert the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that just removes the text nodes:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Q4tv/

```
$('.li-one a').contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: +1 Much more efficient than mine. Now go the extra mile and use `this.parentNode.removeChild(this)`, so that you don't have to construct a new jQuery object on every iteration that encounters a text node.

Answer (score 5):

Cache the image, then empty the anchor element, then re-insert the image:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".li-one a").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $img = $this.find('img');
        $this.empty().append($img);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your html code like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false">
   <img class="theimg" src="...." width="18" height="12" alt="" title="">
   <span>myText</span>
</a>
```

Then add the jQuery script:

```
$(function(){
   $(".li-one a").find("span").text("");
});
```

Comment: If he is able to edit the html, why not just remove the text?

Comment: Let's imagine he wants a button that hide the text or delete it dynamically ? He didn't specified that the HTML couldn't be edited...

Comment: yes... sorry for not mentionning it. i cant modify the html!